# How to import Airflow's PostgresOperator

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to import the `PostgresOperator` from the airflow package:

```
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator
```

But I'm getting the following error: `Cannot find reference 'postgres' in imported module airflow.providers`.

Answer (score 7):

The solution was to run the following in the terminal, using the project's virtualenv: `pip install 'apache-airflow[postgres]'`.

Please notice that it won't work if you don't wrap the name of the package between single-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator
```